# How to find the number of matches a player has played?

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables namely `match` and `player`. I am trying to find the total number of matches played by each player by adding `no_of_wins` and `no_of_loses` columns.

`player`:

```
 id | name   
----|----
  1 | Suhas
  2 | Srivats
  3 | James
  4 | Watson
```

`match`:

```
 id | winner | loser 
----|--------|-------
  1 |      1 |     2
  2 |      1 |     3
  3 |      1 |     4
  4 |      2 |     4
  5 |      4 |     3
  6 |      3 |     2
```

I tried the following `SQL` command:

`select p.id, p.name, count(m.winner) as no_of_wins,count(m.loser) as no_of_loses from player as p left join match as m on p.id=m.winner group by p.id order by p.id;`

This command shows the wrong output for the number of loses.

```
 id |  name   | no_of_wins | no_of_loses 
----|---------|------------|-------------
  1 | Suhas   |          3 |           3
  2 | Srivats |          1 |           1
  3 | James   |          1 |           1
  4 | Watson  |          1 |           1
```

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate aggregated numbers of wins and loses for a player in two queries and (full) join them by a player id:

```
select 
    name, 
    coalesce(wins, 0) as no_of_wins, 
    coalesce(loses, 0) as no_of_loses,
    coalesce(wins, 0) + coalesce(loses, 0) as total
from (
    select winner as id, count(*) as wins
    from match
    group by 1
    ) w
full join (
    select loser as id, count(*) as loses
    from match
    group by 1
    ) l using (id)
full join player using(id)
order by id;

  name   | no_of_wins | no_of_loses | total 
---------+------------+-------------+-------
 Suhas   |          3 |           0 |     3
 Srivats |          1 |           2 |     3
 James   |          1 |           2 |     3
 Watson  |          1 |           2 |     3
(4 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query will cause an error because you didn't add `p.name` to the `GROUP BY` clause.

You'll have to join `match` twice, because these are two independent joins:

```
SELECT p.id,
       p.name,
       COALESCE(w.wins, 0) no_of_wins,
       COALESCE(l.losses, 0) no_of_losses
FROM player p
   LEFT JOIN
      (SELECT winner id,
              count(*) wins
       FROM match
       GROUP BY winner
      ) w
      USING (id)
   LEFT JOIN
      (SELECT loser id,
              count(*) losses
       FROM match
       GROUP BY loser
      ) l
      USING (id);
```

Comment: You'll get doubled values in some rows.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, fixed (looks similar to your solution now...).

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your answer.